# sql как посчитать количество по условию

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть такая таблица:

[image: Таблица1]

Как составить запрос в БД чтобы для каждого поля `parentid` **показывалось количество строк** в которых `type` = 'A'

Такой примерно результат нужен:

[image: Результат]

Comment: ```SELECT parentid, SUM(type = 'A')
FROM source_table
GROUP BY 1```

Comment: В вашем решении parentid будет повторяться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно какой именно SQL нужен, они по немногу все отличаются. Но общая логика такая пишем условие Where потом Group BY.

```
TSQL:

SELECT t.parentid, COUNT(t.parentid)
FROM Table as t
Where t.type= 'A'
Group By t.parentid
```